Subscribe to Redis Channel with Blazor Server
In .NET 7, Blazor Server, using https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics
I'm trying to figure out how to subscribe to a Redis channel, receive constant updates, pass those updates along to all listening components. I have a subscription set up, a middle-man service to pass the data to (which works), and a listener in a component to try to get constant updates. The component isn't getting hit after the RedisService .Invoke() gets called. Any help on the pattern is appreciated.
I attempted to wire up the ConnectionMultiplexer in App.razor, however, it doesn't continue to receive updates of the subscription listener when I navigate away from the home page.
Therefore, in Program.cs, I did the following:
 ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(builder.Configuration.GetSection("RedisSettings").GetValue<string>("server"));
 ISubscriber sub = redis.GetSubscriber();

 sub.Subscribe(builder.Configuration.GetSection("RedisSettings").GetValue<string>("channel")).OnMessage(async channelMessage => {
     await Task.Delay(1000);
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(channelMessage.Message))
     {
         var redis = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RedisService>();
         redis.Set(channelMessage.Message);
     }
 });

My RedisService is simple. // SET DOES get hit multiple times as I publish new data into the channel.
public string Message { get; private set; }
public event Action OnMessageChanged;

public void Set(string message)
{
    Message = message;
    OnMessageChanged?.Invoke();
}

In a component:
@inject RedisService _redis

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    _redis.OnMessageChanged += HandleMessageChanged;
}

void HandleMessageChanged() // THIS DOESN'T GET HIT
{

}


I also reprodced that the event trigger multiple times if not put in program.cs. But if in the program.cs , the following code:
var redis = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RedisService>();

doesn't really get the same "RedisService" instance that you inject using @inject RedisService _redis. It actually create a new "RedisService" instance.
You may consider use static class for "RedisService".
    public static class RedisService
    {
        //create some flag to indcate if a component has been subscribed
        public static bool HasSubScribeToHome { get; set; } = false;
        public static bool HasSubScribeToCounter { get; set; } = false;
        public static string Message { get; private set; }
        public static event Action OnMessageChanged;
        public static void Set(string message)
        {
            Message = message;
            OnMessageChanged?.Invoke();
        }
    }

Then the code would be like
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(channelMessage.Message))
    {
        RedisService.Set(channelMessage.Message);
    }

And the component. (Check if the component has been subscribed to prevent subscribe/trigger twice)
@page "/"
@using StackExchange.Redis
@code{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (!RedisService.HasSubScribeToHome)
        {
            RedisService.OnMessageChanged += HandleMessageChanged;
            RedisService.HasSubScribeToHome = true;
        }
    }
    void HandleMessageChanged() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("called");
    }
}

Teste result

